# How to extract information from json?

Tags: python, json

i am trying to extract from json data some information. On the following code, I first extract the part of json data that contains the information i want and i store it in a file. Then i am trying to open this file and i get the error that follows my code. Can you help me find where i am wrong?

```
import json
import re

input_file = 'path'
text = open(input_file).read()
experience = re.findall(r'Experience":{"positionsMpr":{"showSection":true,"  (.+?),"visible":true,"find_title":"Find others',text)
output_file = open ('/home/evi.nastou/Documenten/LinkedIn_data/Alewijnse/temp', 'w')
output_file.write('{'+experience[0]+'}')
output_file.close()

text = open('path/temp')
input_text = text.read()
data = json.load(input_text)
positions = json.dumps([s['companyName'] for s in data['positions']])
print positions
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = json.load(input_text)
  File "/home/evi.nastou/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 274, in load
     return loads(fp.read(),
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: The document which you are trying to load as dictionary may not be JSON or Python document or it contains illegal caracter in the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `json.loads()` (note the `s`), **or** pass in the file object instead of the result of `.read()`:

```
text = open('path/temp')
data = json.load(text)
```

`json.load()` takes an open file object, but you were passing it a string; `json.loads()` takes a string.